# Rowspan on a single td table failing

Tags: html

I'm echo'ing my table through PHP

Table consists of single td tr's all displaying a 30-minute block

When a reservation consists of an hour I want the td to overlap on the next 30-minute block but I cant' seem to figure out how rowspan works

https://jsfiddle.net/ravf1r3v/4/
Create a small fiddle with single td table

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Plein
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">dklsfjsd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td >dklsfjsd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>dklsfjsd</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you please describe the result you are looking for. `colspan` makes sense only when there is more than one column. However in your case there is only one.

Comment: Was messing with both on the fiddle, changed it back to row now! Does weird thing with single td tables

Comment: I think this should help you to understand: https://jsfiddle.net/cgdfv90g/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a blank `<tr></tr>` below the element with `rowspan`.
Small hack!!

This fiddle will help you understand,
https://jsfiddle.net/josangel555/maajf47p/2/

Answer (score 0):

Add one more td tag to the other rows. Do it this way.

```
<table>
<tr><th>Plein</th></tr>
<tr><td colspan=2>One Hour</td></tr>
<tr><td>1/2 Hour</td><td>1/2 Hour</td></tr>
</table>
```